# Get parent component in Seaside

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

I wanted to see if there is any possibility in Seaside that a child component gets the reference to the parent component, without using the session or parameter passage. That is, the child component making, for example, a call to self gets the parent component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that there is no simple way to do that.

The reason is that subclasses of `WAComponent` (and also `WAPresenter`) have no direct reference to a parent component, since for rendering purposes this is not needed, because the visitor performs a top-down path and depending on a parent element introduces a coupling of some sort, and an instance variable that might not be used.

To overcome that, I have my own `WAComponent` subclass, let's call it `EAMComponent` and this component has a `parent` instance variable (and in my case, also a `model` instance variable).

The `EAMComponent class` implements `on: modelObject in: parentComponent` (as well as `on:` and `in:` that depend on the former, influenced by [Dolphin's implementation of Model-View-Presenter](http://www.object-arts.com/downloads/papers/TwistingTheTriad.PDF)).

So then on the parent component the resulting idiom is something like:

```
createChildrenComponents

  dateComponent := EAMTextComponent on: self date in: self.
  footerComponent := EAMFooterComponent in: self.
```

Then in the footer component you can easily refer to the `parent` that is the object passed as argument to the `in:` part of the selector.

Answer (score 2):

Iirc, the absence of a reference to a Component's parent was a conscious design decision. It is important for keeping components decoupled and self-contained.
This is not to say that esteban's suggestion is wrong, we've also implemented something similar. You can do it, but it may have consequences like lingering references and hurdles to the reusability of components.

Comment: Beside leaking/GC issues (which I have not seen), every coupling point adds constraints. E.g. in a Component with a parent reference, you cannot place such in different parents. Which in my experience is very unlikely, because as said I treat a WAComponent as the "Presenter" in the MVP triad. The view would be the HTML/JS part living in the browser. So what I share is the Model, no the Presenter-View pair.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way of dealing with this in Seaside is to connect the component loosely to its parent using announcements. The parent wires up its children to send it back an announcement.

See: [this example](http://onsmalltalk.com/maintaining-loose-coupling-in-seaside-components)